# For-loop gives output and when run again shows none

Tags: python, for-loop, beautifulsoup

I have written the below code:

```
source2 = url.urlopen("https://www.yelp.com.au/biz/mcfit-berlin-26?osq=gym")
soup = BeautifulSoup(source2, "html.parser")
full_address = soup.find_all("address", class_ = "lemon--address__373c0__2sPac")
for f in full_address:
    print(f.text)
```

When I run it (for the very first time) it gives me the desired output. But if I run it again, it shows nothing (even no error). In the same code in another part (below),

```
source2 = url.urlopen("https://www.yelp.com.au/biz/mcfit-berlin-26?osq=gyms")
soup = BeautifulSoup(source2, "html.parser")
link_info = soup.find_all("p", class_ = "lemon--p__373c0__3Qnnj text__373c0__2Kxyz text-color--normal__373c0__3xep9 text-align--left__373c0__2XGa- text-weight--semibold__373c0__2l0fe text-size--large__373c0__3t60B")


for webadd in link_info[0]:
    print(webadd.text)
```

it will give me a result but if run again will give me the error "IndexError: list index out of range". Can anybody tell me why this strange behaviour of Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: I doubt you're running it like that. You probably create a generator in one cell and then try to iterate it twice in another cell

Comment: If you print the html output after running it twice, you'll see that the info you're looking for isn't loaded into the html, which means it is probably loaded by a script (which in fact it is). That script is always loaded, and you can extract the info from the json more reliably. The other option is you can make a POST request yourself, which might be more complicated.

Comment: @goalie1998 Yes this must be the case. Let me see it. BTW thank you for your valuable suggestion.